# How to change all the extension files from .txt to .ascii?

Tags: linux

I want to change all of my files extension from .txt to .ascii by a script.
This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 ]
then
        dir=$1
else
        echo -n "The director is: "
        read dir
fi

list=`find $dir -name \*.ascii`
for file in $list
do
        name=`basename $file .ascii`
        changedName=$name".txt"
        mv $file $changedName
done
```

This script moves all the .txt files in the script directory with the extension changed to .ascii ... I want all the .txt files to be in there original directory with the extension changed to .ascii.

Comment: just replace `mv $file $changedName` to `cp $file $changedName`. Or did I get the question wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why should such thing be necessary? File name extensions don't really serve any purpose any more. They are a left over from the 1980th and 1990th when content was still determined by them...

Comment: arkascha: for teaching purposes                                                                                 Kevin: I don't want my files to be duplicated. I know my english is bad... I want to change all the exstension files from .txt to .ascii no mater where they are...